# Using functions in Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two object arrays. One array is a list of permissions groups objects, the other is a list of user groups. I'm trying to figure out how to compare the Group Owner (ie. 70) with the list of Users for the matching ID.

The Groups array (ReportModel.report) is structured like this:

```
[{ 
name: Admin,
id: 71,
description: Important Group,
owner: 70,
ownerIsUser: True
 }]
```

The User array (ReportModel.users) is structured like this:

```
[{ 
name: All Users (windows),
id: 70,
domain: c:0!.s|windows,
email: ,
isAdmin: False
 }]
```

Using the group object array, I'm displaying all the groups in a table.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="group in ReportModel.report" on-finish-render
    <td>{{group.id}}</td>
    <td>{{group.description}}</td>
    <td>{{group.owner}}</td>
    <td><td>{{getOwner(group.owner)}}</td></td> //I'm trying to get this cell to display "All Users (windows)"
    <td>{{group.ownerIsUser}}</td>
</tr>
```

**I found a function that does the ID lookup and returns the correct user object from which I can pull the name, but I can't figure out how to call this function in the view within ng-repeat and returns the correct name**

This is my [controller](http://jsfiddle.net/z3rq1ubg/3/):

```
function loadUsers(){
    UserService.loadUsers().then(function (data){
        console.log('getting users');
        $scope.ReportModel.users = data;            })
}


function findById (source, id) {
    return source.filter(function( obj ) {
        // coerce both obj.id and id to numbers 
        // for val & type comparison
        return +obj.id === +id;
    })[ 0 ];
}

$scope.getOwner = function (ownerID) {
    console.log('get owner called', ownerID);
    var owner = findById($scope.ReportModel.users, ownerID);
    console.log(owner.name);
    return owner.name;
}
```

Comment: You can just call that function `<td>{{getUsers(group.owner)}}</td>`

Comment: I tried you're suggestion but I'm getting an interpolation error http://jsfiddle.net/uyy0kfjp/

Comment: @PSL your solution worked for me. I just needed to make sure that all my users were populated before ng-repeat ran. So it was a timing issue. Thanks for your help. If you submit it as the answer I can make it off as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Sure added as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making my comment an answer.

You can use any expression that can be validated against the scope in the binding. So in your case you could do:-

```
<td><td>{{getOwner(group.owner)}}</td></td>
```

group.owner from the iterated group and call getOwner function from the scope.

and in your scope:-

```
$scope.getOwner = function (owner) {
    //Your logic that returns the owner.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using the finById function in your controller is correct. The reason you cannot call it from your html is because the method is not bound to your scope. Change the function definition in your controller to:

```
$scope.findById = function(source, id) {
    return source.filter(function( obj ) {
        // coerce both obj.id and id to numbers 
        // for val & type comparison
        return +obj.id === +id;
    })[ 0 ];
}
```

Comment: I made  some change to the controller and added another function to call the findById, so it's not being used directly by the view. But I'm getting this error: Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{getOwner(group.owner)}}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined